# How to use research Kit framework in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, researchkit

I am making a health app using researchKit. I want to do this in Xamarin as I already have a lot of shared code which can be used in Xamarin. However, research Kit has not been integrated into Xamarin . I am thinking of binding the framework to my project in Xamarin. But I have no idea how to do it. I am new to developing in Xamarin. Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+xamarin+binding http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

Comment: is this approach correct of using research kit in xamarain!